# What is root cause of this huge system load

Tags: centos, centos6

I am totally puzzled here.

A couple of CentOS 6.6 x64 servers have unexpected huge system load.
I think I have checked everything, but no idea about reasons why.

I guess there should be a bottleneck somewhere with any resource that processes are waiting for , but which one ?

- CPU is not used that much
- RAM, there is plenty of it, and no SWAP.
- local DISK is almost not used
- NETWORK is fine ; activity is not suspicious and no RX/TX error.
- There are several NFS mounts (especially for user homedirs), but activity is normal. Few requests.
- no process in WAIT queue, no zombie...

First, top output :

```
top - 11:29:05 up 110 days, 18:47, 255 users,  load average: 45.49, 46.77, 46.28
Tasks: 2447 total,   5 running, 2442 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 23.9%us, 12.2%sy,  0.7%ni, 61.5%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.4%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65965108k total, 55072032k used, 10893076k free,   186028k buffers
Swap:  3144700k total,        0k used,  3144700k free,  7498236k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND53464 root      20   0 30144 3344 1136 R 15.4  0.0   0:00.15 top
53567 mguedira  20   0  306m  12m 9748 R 12.4  0.0   0:00.08 nautilus
  399 amakovsk  20   0  148m 4588 2736 S  4.6  0.0 148:28.10 gvfsd-trash
```

Then dstat :

```
----system---- proc ----total-cpu-usage---- ------memory-usage----- ----swap--- ---load-avg--- --filesystem- --io/total-
  date/time   |tota|usr sys idl wai hiq siq| used  buff  cach  free| used  free| 1m   5m  15m |files  inodes| read  writ
30-06 11:31:14|2448| 25  12  61   0   0   1|45.2G  182M 7332M 10.4G|   0  3071M|46.2 46.5 46.3|  175k   374k|0.13  18.9 
30-06 11:31:15|2449| 66  18  15   0   0   1|45.2G  182M 7332M 10.3G|   0  3071M|46.2 46.5 46.3|  175k   374k|   0     0 
30-06 11:31:16|2448| 71  16  10   0   0   3|45.3G  182M 7333M 10.3G|   0  3071M|46.2 46.5 46.3|  175k   374k|   0     0 
30-06 11:31:17|2448| 63  18  16   0   0   3|45.3G  182M 7333M 10.3G|   0  3071M|46.2 46.5 46.3|  175k   374k|   0  5.00 
30-06 11:31:18|2448| 64  22  10   1   1   4|45.2G  182M 7333M 10.4G|   0  3071M|46.2 46.5 46.3|  175k   374k|   0     0 
30-06 11:31:19|2448| 71  17  11   0   0   1|45.2G  182M 7333M 10.3G|   0  3071M|45.7 46.4 46.2|  175k   374k|   0  4.00 
30-06 11:31:20|2448| 67  18  12   0   0   3|45.2G  182M 7333M 10.3G|   0  3071M|45.7 46.4 46.2|  175k   374k|   0     0 
30-06 11:31:21|2448| 62  20  14   1   0   3|45.2G  182M 7333M 10.4G|   0  3071M|45.7 46.4 46.2|  175k   374k|   0     0 
30-06 11:31:22|2448| 62  20  15   1   0   3|45.2G  182M 7334M 10.3G|   0  3071M|45.7 46.4 46.2|  175k   374k|   0  70.0 
30-06 11:31:23|2448| 70  17  12   0   0   1|45.2G  182M 7334M 10.3G|   0  3071M|45.7 46.4 46.2|  175k   374k|   0     0 
30-06 11:31:24|2448| 72  17   9   0   0   2|45.3G  182M 7334M 10.3G|   0  3071M|46.0 46.5 46.2|  175k   374k|   0  4.00 
30-06 11:31:25|2448| 65  20  12   0   0   4|45.3G  182M 7334M 10.3G|   0  3071M|46.0 46.5 46.2|  175k   374k|   0     0 
30-06 11:31:26|2448| 73  16   9   0   0   2|45.3G  182M 7334M 10.3G|   0  3071M|46.0 46.5 46.2|  175k   374k|   0     0 
30-06 11:31:27|2449| 64  17  16   1   0   2|45.2G  182M 7334M 10.4G|   0  3071M|46.0 46.5 46.2|  175k   374k|   0  7.00 
30-06 11:31:28|2448| 74  16   8   0   0   3|45.2G  182M 7334M 10.3G|   0  3071M|46.0 46.5 46.2|  175k   374k|   0     0 
30-06 11:31:29|2448| 77  16   4   0   0   3|45.2G  182M 7334M 10.3G|   0  3071M|45.9 46.5 46.2|  175k   374k|   0  21.0 
30-06 11:31:30|2448| 72  17   8   1   0   2|45.2G  182M 7335M 10.4G|   0  3071M|45.9 46.5 46.2|  175k   374k|   0     0 
30-06 11:31:31|2448| 67  18  13   0   0   2|45.2G  182M 7335M 10.4G|   0  3071M|45.9 46.5 46.2|  175k   374k|   0     0 
30-06 11:31:32|2448| 65  18  13   1   0   3|45.2G  182M 7335M 10.4G|   0  3071M|45.9 46.5 46.2|  175k   374k|   0  10.0
```

I know there are about 2500 processes, about 40 different users, about 50 Gnome+KDE sessions. On a 2-cores server.
And so what ?

I have many other servers with the exact same configuration, same number of jobs, users and sessions. But their load is lower than 1, and hardly more than 2 or 3 in worst case.
But here, load is greater than 40 !!

Any idea ?

Comment: What about free space and free inodes on mouned filesystems?

Comment: Does `grep ' D ' /proc/*/task/*/stat` say anything?

Comment: Yes, 44 processes waiting for disk access... Most of them are gvfsd-trash. What can I do ? Kill them all ? - without noticing users ? -

Comment: As for free space and inodes, local disk is not used. Most of access are on NFS and I can hardly answer about inodes ( Netapp storage at ends... ).